# Как в проэкте заставить компилироваться XSD dataset

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть проэкт. В нём использована xsd-dataset. Проэкт не публикуется (ф-ция publish), просто копирование не позволяет поднять проэкт. При сборке в студии ругается на dsAdmin.xsd как будто это сs файл на строку `<?xml version`

> A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> Expected class delegate enum interface or struct

В ствойствах xsd заполено так:

```
Build action    = Compile
Copy to         = Do not copy
Custom tool     = MSDataSetGenerator
CustomToolNamesp= пусто
FileName        = dsAdmin.xsd
```

Файлы cs xsc xss сгенерировались. Студия 2005. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы указали `Build action = Compile` вот он и пытается скомпилироваться. Укажите None или Resource.

Comment: Да, собралось..